# Can get MAC Address of peripheral after pairing in Core Bluetooth iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

I'm a newbie in Core Bluetooth LE. Now I want to get MAC Address of peripheral after pairing successfully. As far as I know, after pairing will return a UUID, name and RSSI, i dont see MAC Address.So Can I do that? Any help or answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973098/get-mac-address-of-bluetooth-low-energy-peripheral