# Get MAC address in scan response packet for BLE Device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Refer to question: [Get MAC address of bluetooth low energy peripheral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973098/get-mac-address-of-bluetooth-low-energy-peripheral/18973205#comment89030110_18973205)

We have board where we have kept MAC id in encrypted form in advertisement packet and reading those MAC-id in our iOS App. Since Apple actually suppress MAC id information for BLE device Will it be problem (App rejection) if manufacturer puts this in packet and app reads it?

Comment: Only Apple can answer 100% but I wouldn't think it would be a problem. They aren't going to analyse the data your device sends